# How to make current date is visible remaining invisible in datePicker plugin?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i am trying to current date is visible remaining dates should be invisible in  datePicker  plugin.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
       numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {

         $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate",selected)
       }

  });
   $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
       $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", new Date())
    }

  });  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the remaining after dates, you can use the `minDate: 1,` attribute

```
$("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
numberOfMonths: 2,
minDate: 1,
onSelect: function(selected) {
   $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", new Date())
}

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/549/)